# Is there a Rails gem for management of a "multi-visit pass" scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, user-accounts

I'm a Rails noob. I'm looking to implement an application where users can purchase a multi-visit pass, then spend the credits week-by-week.

For example, register and login, then purchase 10 visits at a gym - the system should list *10 remaining visits*. Sign up to a class and *9 remaining visits* are listed. When the credits are low, remind the user to top them up with another 10-visit pass, etc.

I know I can use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to manage the authentication and authorisation aspects.

My question is whether there's already a gem to handle the management of the user's credits, or whether I'd need to write this from scratch.

I've searched https://rubygems.org/gems/rails with no luck, but it's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a gem to do that, but it should be pretty simple to code:

- Add `remaining_visits` to your User model and table.
- Do `current_user.update(remaining_visits: current_user.remaining_visits+10)` when a ticket is purchased.
- Copy Devise sessions controller into `app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb`.
- Inside this controller, add this kind of code to `create` (where the user logs in): `current_user.update(remaining_visits: current_user.remaining_visits-1)`.

Note: Instead of copying Devise sessions controller you can just overwrite the `create` action.

Comment: Thanks. I definitely appreciate the tips and suggestions.